# Multistep form - with field filled by jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have problem with script who filled input field when one value is less then 4. When the value is less then 4 the script filling field but the value is not selected, so when I'm going to next step I have no value in this field. When the value is greater then 4 everything is ok (the value is also filling by jquery).

```
  function compute() {
    if( parseInt($("#finish_day").val()) < 4 ) { 
      $('#return_car').children('#return_car option[value=' + $('#get_car').val() + ']').attr('selected', true).siblings().attr('disabled', true);            if  
      ($('#return_car').val()) $('#return_car').change();        
    }
    else {
       $('#get_car > option, #return_car > option').prop('disabled', false);            
       $('#three_day').hide(2000, function () {                
          $(this).remove();            
       });        
    }    
  }
  $('select#get_car').change(compute);$('input#finish_day').change(compute);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $('#return_car').children('#return_car option[value=' + $('#get_car').val() + ']').prop('selected', true).siblings().prop('disabled', true);


  $('#return_car').children('option[value=' + $('#get_car').val() + ']').prop('selected', true).siblings().prop({disabled:true,selected:false});
```

Solution is add disabled:true and selected.